# pymrio: how to perform product or sector-specific analysis?

Tags: life-cycle-analysis

I'm using the Python tool pymrio to do emission analysis for various traded goods (using Exiobase).

I see how production and consumption based emissions are calculated on per-country basis, in the available getting-started descriptions on [openresearch](https://openresearchsoftware.metajnl.com/articles/10.5334/jors.251/) and on the [python package](https://pymrio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html) page.

But: How to use the tool's functionality to **estimate the consumption based impact**, e.g. GHG emissions, or simply CO2, or in the worst case simply, e.g. Coal or so use, **for a given sector in a given region**, ideally per kg (or per € of value) of the sector's core output.

**Say: In Exiobase 2 or Exiobase 3, for "Pigs" in "Germany", as a random example.**

Does the tool readily provide functionality to calculate this embodied impact? Or does one have to manually work with the matrices after loading the database?